# MySQL: SELECT and JOIN with not exists values?

Tags: mysql, join

How can i SELECT data from two tables using 'JOIN' operator, if some values with `cat_idx` and `tar_id` from `categories` (`tar_id` = 87) does not exists in `time_discounts` table. (I need to print '0' in this case)

See My SQL Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `tar_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_idx` int(11) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `time_discounts` (
  `dis_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `tar_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_idx` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `discount`double NOT NULL
);

insert into categories values(null, 87, 122);
insert into categories values(null, 82, 120);
insert into categories values(null, 87, 128);
insert into categories values(null, 81, 14);
insert into categories values(null, 87, 135);
insert into categories values(null, 87, 140);

insert into time_discounts values(null, 87, 122, 2.34);
insert into time_discounts values(null, 82, 120, 9.22);
insert into time_discounts values(null, 81, 14, 2.11);
insert into time_discounts values(null, 87, 135, 9.35);
insert into time_discounts values(null, 80, 11, 83.22);
```

For tar_id = 87 and cat_idx = 122 from `categories` table we can find values from `time_discounts` table, but for cat_idx = 140 and 128 values does not exists in `time_discounts` table. In this case output should be something like this:

```
| tar_id | cat_idx | discount |
|--------|---------|----------|
|     87 |     122 |     2.34 |
|     87 |     128 |     0    |
|     87 |     135 |     9.35 |
|     87 |     140 |     0    |
```

My query:

```
SELECT `c`.`tar_id`, `c`.`cat_idx`, IFNULL(`td`.`discount`, 0)
FROM `categories` AS `c`
LEFT JOIN `time_discounts` AS `td`
    ON `td`.`tar_id` = `c`.`tar_id`
    AND `td`.`cat_idx` = `c`.`cat_idx`;
```

But i need to filter data by tar_id = 87 and if i add `AND c.tar_id = 87` i also gets all values from `time_discounts`, not only tar_id = 87.

Please help and sorry for my english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `AND c.tar_id = 87` to `WHERE c.tar_id = 87`.

Your soultion would work only if it was an `INNER JOIN` instead.
With `LEFT JOIN` it works different. The filter is applied for the join predicate and the result is different.